# Using Google Apps Script, is it possible to allow users only access few spreadsheet records?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

What I want to do is onOpen, find out who the user is and store their email address in a variable. That part is no problem. The issue comes next.

Is it possible to then say, Display only the records that contain that user's email address?

Comment: Short answer is no. Think about a UI as a standalone webapp that shows selected data depending on the logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Build an app (uiapp or htmlseevice)